# d3 Stacked Bar Chart Not Updating

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm working on a stacked bar/multiples chart following Mike's example at http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4679202/. This works great, and my chart transitions just fine between the multiples and stacks with the starting dataset. See the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/sc4jaxg3/.

However, when I try to Update() and join to a second test dataset...nothing happens. I suspect this is due to some obvious difference between the data assigned to the group "g" and the "rects" within it, but I'm at my wits end as to why it won't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Second question and less of a priority: I have labels above each "rect" showing the actual numeric value, and it appears fine for all but the first rects of each group.

Please see my js code below. Thanks!

```
var testViz = [

{ gender: "F", group: "18-24", total: 14 },
{ gender: "F", group: "25-34", total: 52 },
{ gender: "F", group: "35-44", total: 125 },
{ gender: "F", group: "45-54", total: 139 },
{ gender: "F", group: "55-64", total: 140 },
{ gender: "F", group: "65-74", total: 43 },
{ gender: "F", group: "75-84", total: 5 },
{ gender: "M", group: "18-24", total: 8 },
{ gender: "M", group: "25-34", total: 15 },
{ gender: "M", group: "35-44", total: 36 },
{ gender: "M", group: "45-54", total: 45 },
{ gender: "M", group: "55-64", total: 34 },
{ gender: "M", group: "65-74", total: 21 },
{ gender: "M", group: "75-84", total: 3 }

];

var testViz2 = [

{ gender: "F", group: "18-24", total: 14 },
{ gender: "F", group: "25-34", total: 111 },
{ gender: "F", group: "35-44", total: 134 },
{ gender: "F", group: "45-54", total: 139 },
{ gender: "F", group: "55-64", total: 140 },
{ gender: "F", group: "65-74", total: 43 },
{ gender: "F", group: "75-84", total: 2 },
{ gender: "M", group: "18-24", total: 8 },
{ gender: "M", group: "25-34", total: 15 },
{ gender: "M", group: "35-44", total: 23 },
{ gender: "M", group: "45-54", total: 45 },
{ gender: "M", group: "55-64", total: 34 },
{ gender: "M", group: "65-74", total: 112 },
{ gender: "M", group: "75-84", total: 3 }

];

var margin = { top: 0, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 60 },
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var y0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([height, 0], .2);

var y1 = d3.scale.linear();

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1, 0);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var nest = d3.nest()
    .key(function (d) { return d.group; });

var stack = d3.layout.stack()
    .values(function (d) { return d.values; })
    .x(function (d) { return d.group; })
    .y(function (d) { return d.total; })
    .out(function (d, y0) { d.valueOffset = y0; });

var color = d3.scale.ordinal().range(["#0094cc", "#FF8408"]);

var svg = d3.select("#genderChart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

this.DrawGenderChart = function (data) {

data.forEach(function (d) {
    d.total = +d.total;
});

var dataByGender = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.gender; })
    .entries(data);

stack(dataByGender);
x.domain(dataByGender[0].values.map(function (d) { return d.group; }));
y0.domain(dataByGender.map(function (d) { return d.key; }));
y1.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.total; })]).range([y0.rangeBand(), 0]);

var group = svg.selectAll(".gender")
    .data(dataByGender)
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "gender")
    .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(0," + y0(d.key) + ")"; });

group.append("text")
    .attr("class", "gender-label")
    .attr("x", -50)
    .attr("y", function (d) { return y1(d.values[0].total / 2); })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function (d) {
        var output;

        if (d.key == "F")
            output = "Female";
        else if (d.key == "M")
            output = "Male";
        else
            output = "Unknown";

        return output;
    });

var rects = group.selectAll("rect")
    .data(function (d) { return d.values; })

rects.exit().remove();

rects.enter().append("rect")
    .style("fill", function (d) { return color(d.gender); })
    .attr("x", function (d) { return x(d.group); })
    .attr("y", function (d) { return y1(d.total); })
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .attr("height", function (d) { return y0.rangeBand() - y1(d.total); });

group.selectAll("text")
    .data(function (d) { console.log(d); return d.values; })
  .enter().append("text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("class", "rect-label")
    .attr("x", function (d) { return x(d.group) + (x.rangeBand() / 2); })
    .attr("y", function (d) { return y1(d.total) - 10; })
    .text(function (d) { return d.total; });


group.filter(function (d, i) { return !i; }).append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + y0.rangeBand() + ")")
    .call(xAxis);


d3.selectAll(".genderCompare").on("click", function () {


    if (this.textContent === "Compare by Gender") transitionMultiples();
    else transitionStacked();

});

function transitionMultiples() {
    var t = svg.transition().duration(750),
        g = t.selectAll(".gender").attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(0," + y0(d.key) + ")"; });
    g.selectAll("rect").attr("y", function (d) { return y1(d.total); });
    g.select(".gender-label").attr("y", function (d) { return y1(d.values[0].total / 2); })
    g.selectAll(".rect-label").attr("opacity", 1);
}

function transitionStacked() {
    var t = svg.transition().duration(750),
        g = t.selectAll(".gender").attr("transform", "translate(0," + y0(y0.domain()[0]) + ")");
    g.selectAll("rect").attr("y", function (d) { return y1(d.total + d.valueOffset); });
    g.select(".gender-label").attr("y", function (d) { return y1(d.values[0].total / 2 + d.values[0].valueOffset); })
    g.selectAll(".rect-label").attr("opacity", 0);
}
};

DrawGenderChart(testViz);
DrawGenderChart(testViz2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the filter selection JS code by this:

```
d3.selectAll(".compare-criteria").on("click", function () {
   if (this.className.indexOf("genderCompare") > 0) 
     transitionMultiples();
   else 
     transitionStacked();
});
```

And the html with this:

```
<div id="genderChart">
    <span class="compare-criteria ageCompare">Compare by Age</span>
    <span class="compare-criteria genderCompare option-selected">Compare by Gender</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Which is a good idea and I will probably implement. But the transition between Multiples and Stacked already works fine. But if I try to change or update the underlying data, nothing happens. That is my primary problem. Thanks.